# How to plot this pdf?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Let $x\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $y=\max\{e^{x-1}-\kappa,0\}$. How to get and plot the pdf of y? In particular, there will be a probability mass at $y=0$, which is a nondifferentiable point. I tried

```
pdfY[y_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {1/(y + κ) f[Log[y + κ] + 1], y > 0},
   {N[Integrate[f[x], {x, -10, Log[κ] + 1}]], y = 0},
   {0, y < 0}
  }
```

but it does not work well.

Comment: You'll need to provide values for all of the parameters: $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\kappa$.

Comment: They can be $\mu=\sigma=1$, $\kappa=3$, for instance.

Comment: The PDF can be defined for absolutely continuous random variables only.

Comment: There will be a probability mass at $y=0$. It is neither PDF nor PMF?

Comment: Based on your question and the reasonable challenges by @user64494, I went and asked a similar question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491443/what-are-reasonable-ways-to-plot-the-pdf-of-a-censored-random-variable/491506#491506.  I think the answer there says that your "pdf" is neither fish nor fowl but that it is a something that can be plotted.

Comment: Thanks, @JimB. I am not allowed to comment there, so want to provide some content here. The reason that I want to plot the "density" is because I am looking at a dataset of individual choices and each choice is constrained to be non-negative. I want to plot a theoretical "density" and compare it with the empirical histogram.

Answer (score 0):

```
TransformedDistribution[Max[E^(x-1)-κ,0],x\[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ,σ]]//PDF[#,y]&
```

```
1/2 DiracDelta[y+κ] (1+Erf[(1-μ+Log[y+κ])/(Sqrt[2] σ)]) (-1+UnitStep[-y]) (UnitStep[-y] (-1+UnitStep[-κ])-UnitStep[-κ])-DiracDelta[y] (1+Erf[(1-μ+Log[κ])/(Sqrt[2] σ)]) (-1+UnitStep[-κ])-(E^(-((1-μ+Log[y+κ])^2/(2 σ^2))) (-1+UnitStep[-y]) (1+UnitStep[-y] (-1+UnitStep[-y-κ]) (-1+UnitStep[-κ])-UnitStep[-y-κ] UnitStep[-κ]))/(Sqrt[2 π] (y+κ) σ)
```

then you can plot it.

Comment: This result makes no sense in traditional math since the integral for CDF through PDF makes no sense. The PDF exists only for absolutely continuous distributions (see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Continuous_distribution and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function ). Such approach leads to bugs e.g. as in https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/207769-Bug-In-Probability. In order to calculate the mean and so on [the Riemann-Stielttjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral) is used.

Comment: In this case it's simpler to plot the CDF as it is defined everywhere.  However, there's no reason not to plot the PDF where the random variable is continuous. In this case one would likely put a dot maybe at (0,0) and note that there's a probability mass of  $\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\log (\kappa )-\mu +1}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+1\right)$ at $y=0$ where $\kappa>0$.

Comment: @JimB: Can you ground "However, there's no reason not to plot the PDF where the random variable is continuous"? I prefer arguments over empty words.

Comment: Sorry, I was way too loose with my words.  The PDF will exist at any point where the CDF is differentiable.  And the PDF does not have to exist at every point to disallow the plotting of the PDF at the points where it does exist.  In the OP's example, suppose the $\kappa$ is very small resulting in a very small probability mass at 0 but plotting the PDF where the PDF exists will still give an appropriate picture of the distribution of that random variable.  However, I am unaware of a standard way to display the probability mass in such a situation other than including an explanatory note.

Comment: I was wondering how is the "density function" defined in such cases where there is a probability mass at a point and the CDF is differentiable at other points?

Comment: @JimB:: See [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) to this end. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Thanks.  I've gone ahead and asked the folks on CrossValidated:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491443/what-are-reasonable-ways-to-plot-the-pdf-of-a-censored-random-variable.

Comment: @JimB: BTW, the comment to your  question on CrossValidated refers to  an unknown math journal Information Visualization
2019, Vol. 18(3) 311–317.

Comment: @user64494.  OK.  I now understand (from an answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491443/what-are-reasonable-ways-to-plot-the-pdf-of-a-censored-random-variable) why what is being ask to plot is not a pdf.  However, there does appear to be a few ways to plot something for this example that can give one an idea as to the shape of the distribution analogous to a pdf.

Comment: @JimB: That approach is primitive and misleading: the PDF in the case under consideration does not exist so it is impossible to plot it. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

distY = TransformedDistribution[Max[E^(x - 1) - κ, 0],
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ]];
```

`distY` inherits the assumptions from the `NormalDistribution`

```
dpa = DistributionParameterAssumptions[distY]

(* μ ∈ Reals && σ > 0 *)

pdf[y_] = PDF[distY, y]

(* 1/2 DiracDelta[
   y + κ] (1 + 
    Erf[(1 - μ + Log[y + κ])/(Sqrt[2] σ)]) UnitStep[y] - (
 E^(-((1 - μ + Log[y + κ])^2/(2 σ^2)))
   UnitStep[y] (-1 + UnitStep[-y - κ]))/(
 Sqrt[2 π] (y + κ) σ) - 
 1/2 DiracDelta[
   y] (1 + Erf[(1 - μ + Log[κ])/(Sqrt[2] σ)]) (-1 + 
    UnitStep[-κ]) *)
```

Checking the total probability (this is quite slow),

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Assuming[dpa, Integrate[pdf[y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}] // Simplify]]

(* {40.1147, ConditionalExpression[1, Re[κ] >= 0 && Im[κ] == 0]} *)
```

Consequently, this requires `κ >= 0` and

```
distY = TransformedDistribution[Max[E^(x - 1) - κ, 0],
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ], 
   Assumptions -> κ >= 0];

dpa = DistributionParameterAssumptions[distY]

(* κ >= 0 && μ ∈ Reals && σ > 0 *)

pdf[y_] = PDF[distY, y]

(* 1/2 DiracDelta[
   y] (1 + Erf[(1 - μ + Log[κ])/(Sqrt[2] σ)]) - (
 E^(-((1 - μ + Log[y + κ])^2/(
   2 σ^2))) (-1 + UnitStep[-y]))/(Sqrt[2 π] (y + κ) σ) *)

Assuming[dpa, Integrate[pdf[y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)
```

This is a mixed distribution with a discrete probability for `y == 0` of

```
pdf2[0] = 1/2*(1 + Erf[(1 - μ + Log[κ])/(Sqrt[2]*σ)]);
```

and a continuous probability distribution for `y > 0` of

```
pdf2[y_] = ConditionalExpression[
  Simplify[-((-1 + UnitStep[-y])/
          (E^((1 - μ + Log[y + κ])^2/(2*σ^2))*
        (Sqrt[2*Pi]*(y + κ)*σ))), y > 0], y > 0]

(* ConditionalExpression[
   1/(E^((1 - μ + Log[y + κ])^2/(2*σ^2))*
        (Sqrt[2*Pi]*(y + κ)*σ)), y > 0] *)

Assuming[dpa,
 pdf2[0] + Integrate[pdf2[y], {y, 0, Infinity}] //
  FullSimplify]

(* 1 *)
```

Plotting,

```
μ = 1; σ = 1; κ = 3;

Show[
 Plot[pdf2[y], {y, -1/2, 5}],
 DiscretePlot[pdf2[y], {y, 0, 0},
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you repeat the answer of  @AsukaMinato in other formulas? See the comments to it.

Comment: @user64494 - Previous answer did not include the required assumption that `kappa >= 0` without which the distribution is not valid. Expressions after that additional assumption are simpler. Also, the question fundamentally was about plotting ("How to plot this pdf") which was not previously done. Mixed distributions (hybrids of discrete and continuous distributions) occur in the real world (e.g., analysis of meteor burst communications). I recall a book by Papoulis back in the early 1970s on "Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes" that covered them. Or look on the internet.