# Bug in density function

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics

Executing

```
a = PDF[TransformedDistribution[
x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}], 
 y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}], 
 z \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]}], t] //AbsoluteTiming
```

, I obtain  a long output (see it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/942205z50s4u9qc/pdf1.pdf?dl=0)) in 5747.98 sec.
The result is not correct in view of

```
Plot[a[[2]], {t, -1, 13}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

since any PDF cannot take negative values. Is there a workaround?

Comment: What it should look like for reference:
```dist = HistogramDistribution[
   Norm[#]^2 & /@ 
    RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}], 
     10000000]
   , 250];
Plot[PDF[dist, t], {t, -1, 13}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All]```

Comment: Also worth noting that removing a dimension (e.g z) produces a correct result for 2D.

Comment: @flinty: Thank you for your interest to the question. Indeed, the plot should be similar to the histgram of `Norm[#]^2 & /@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}],       10000000]`. Yes, Mathematica produces the correct result in two dimensions.

Comment: The results of `b = CDF[TransformedDistribution[
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}], 
     y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}], 
     z \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]}], t]`  in 10571. sec and  `Plot[b, {t,-1,13},PlotStyle->Thick]` are even worse.

Comment: If you found an obvious bug, you should report it to Wolfram Support.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## The Issue

Mathematica appears to have a lot of trouble with doing the integrals involved in finding the PDF. I'm not sure what's going on under the hood, but doing some playing around suggests Mathematica is somehow screwing up when it comes to the degeneracies involved with having a non-symmetric interval involving both positive and negative numbers. E.g. in 1D the PDF of $A=X^2$ with $X\sim U(-1,2)$ is given by
$$
f_A(a)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{a}} & 0<a<1 \\
\frac{1}{6 \sqrt{a}} & 1<a<4\\
0&\text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
which is discontinuous because $0<a<1$ get contributions both from when $-1<x\leq0$ and $0<x<1$ while $1<a<4$ get contributions only from $1<x<2$. Mathematica has no problem handling this in 1D. In 2D, these degenerate contributions become more complex but Mathematica still gets it right. However, in 3D it seems Mathematica no longer handles these degeneracies correctly. This may be caused by the fact that Mathematica has to resort to different techniques in 3D because it cannot evaluate the integrals in the same way. I ran into some of this playing around with using the direct [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_scalar) for the transformation. Naively applying it works in 2D but not 3D. Doing some change of variables stuff (e.g. $w=a-x^2$) gives integrals of the form$^1$
$$
f_A(a)=\int _{a-b}^{a-c}\int _{w-d}^{w-e}\int _{v-f}^{v-g}\frac{\delta (k) dkdvdw}{8 \sqrt{v-k} \sqrt{w-v} \sqrt{a-w}}
$$
which Mathematica can do in 2D (same form with one less $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and integral) but not 3D, for all values of $b-g\in\{0,1,4\}$.

Whatever the underlying reason, here's an example of where Mathematica gets it wrong and how we can work around that. Consider the CDF in 3D for $1<a<2$

```
Integrate[Boole[x^2+y^2+z^2<= a], 
{x,y,z} ∈ Cuboid[{-1,-1,-1},{2,2,2}], Assumptions-> 1<a<2]/3^3/. a-> 3/2
```

gives $\sim 0.045$ but the correct answer is $\sim 0.265$ and can be found by handling the cases separately:

```
{r1,r2}={Cuboid[{-1,-1,-1},{1,1,1}],Cuboid[{-1,-1,1},{1,1,2}]};
(Integrate[Boole[x^2+y^2+z^2<= a], {x,y,z} ∈ r1, Assumptions-> 1<a<2]+
3 Integrate[Boole[x^2+y^2+z^2<= a], {x,y,z} ∈ r2, Assumptions-> 1<a<2])/3^3/. a-> 3/2
```

Which comes from the fact that for $1<a<2$ the magnitude of $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all $\leq1$ or two are $\leq1$ and one is $>1$. The factor of three arises because any one of the three $x$, $y$, or $z$ can be the one which is $>1$. This motivates our workaround.

## A workaround

We handle the cases manually for Mathematica, what's given here should work well in any dimension (though some tweaking would need to be done). We need to consider the following regions and multiplicities

```
dim=3
b3 = Union[Tuples[{{-1, 1}, {1, 2}}, dim], SameTest -> (Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &)];
regs = Cuboid @@ Thread[#] & /@ b3;
mult = Length@Permutations[#] & /@ b3;
```

We then define the integral for the CDF

```
int[as_]:=int[as]=mult.(ParallelMap[Integrate[Boole[x^2+y^2+z^2 <= a],
{x,y,z} ∈ #, Assumptions -> as] &, regs])/3^dim
```

This sums the integral in each region weighted by `mult`. Clearly this will be a piecewise depending on the value of $a$. The pieces will clearly have bounds that are integers, so we could run `int[#-1<a<#] &/@ Range[4 dim]`. But we can save a little work by explicitly finding the bounds on each piece:

```
bounds = #[[1]] < a < #[[2]] & /@ Partition[Union[Total /@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2}^2, dim]], 2, 1]
```

The general idea is the pieces will be at the values of $\sum_{i=1}^d a_i^2$ with $a_i\in\{0,1,2\}$ in dimension $d$.

We can then get the pieces of the CDF (~20min for me) with

```
AbsoluteTiming[cdfs = int /@ bounds;]
```

The PDF is the derivative of the CDF so we have

```
pdfs = D[cdfs,a];
```

or for an extra 20s

```
pdfs = ParallelTable[FullSimplify[D[FullSimplify[funcs[[k]],bounds[[k]]],a],bounds[[k]]],
{k,Length@bounds}];
```

and finally

```
pdf[a_]=Piecewise[Thread[{pdfs,bounds}]];
```

For easy reference that gives `pdf[a]` as

```
pdf[a_]=Piecewise[{{(2 Sqrt[a] \[Pi])/27,0<a<1},{-(1/27) (-3+Sqrt[a]) \[Pi],1<a<2},{1/27 (3 (\[Pi]-2 ArcTan[Sqrt[-2+a]])+2 Sqrt[a] (ArcCsc[1-a]+ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2+a)/a]])),2<a<3},{1/108 (9 \[Pi]-12 ArcTan[Sqrt[-2+a]]+4 Sqrt[a] (ArcCsc[1-a]+ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2+a)/a]])),3<a<4},{1/54 ((33/2-6 Sqrt[a]) \[Pi]-6 ArcTan[Sqrt[-2+a]]+2 Sqrt[a] (ArcCsc[1-a]+ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2+a)/a]])),4<a<5},{1/108 (3 (7 \[Pi]+8 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-5+a]]-16 ArcTan[Sqrt[-5+a]]-4 ArcTan[Sqrt[-2+a]])+4 Sqrt[a] (ArcCsc[1-a]+ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2+a)/a]]-6 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[(-5+a) a]])),5<a<6},{1/108 (15 \[Pi]+12 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-5+a]]-24 ArcTan[Sqrt[-5+a]]-4 Sqrt[a] (ArcTan[2 Sqrt[(-5+a)/a]]+4 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[(-5+a) a]]+ArcTan[2 Sqrt[a],Sqrt[-5+a]])),6<a<8},{1/108 (-9 \[Pi]+48 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-8+a]]+12 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-5+a]]-24 ArcTan[Sqrt[-5+a]]-4 Sqrt[a] (ArcCot[2 Sqrt[a/(-5+a)]]-6 ArcTan[Sqrt[(-8+a)/a]]+ArcTan[2 Sqrt[(-5+a)/a]]+4 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[(-5+a) a]])),8<a<9},{1/54 (-3 \[Pi]+12 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-8+a]]+2 Sqrt[a] (ArcTan[Sqrt[(-8+a)/a]]-ArcTan[4/Sqrt[(-8+a) a]])),9<a<12}},0]
```

i.e.
$$
\begin{cases}
 \frac{2 \pi  \sqrt{a}}{27} & 0<a<1 \\
 -\frac{1}{27} \pi  \left(\sqrt{a}-3\right) & 1<a<2 \\
 \frac{1}{27} \left(3 \left(\pi -2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a-2}\right)\right)+2 \sqrt{a} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-2}{a}}\right)+\csc ^{-1}(1-a)\right)\right) & 2<a<3 \\
 \frac{1}{108} \left(-12 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a-2}\right)+4 \sqrt{a} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-2}{a}}\right)+\csc ^{-1}(1-a)\right)+9 \pi \right) & 3<a<4 \\
 \frac{1}{54} \left(\pi  \left(\frac{33}{2}-6 \sqrt{a}\right)-6 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a-2}\right)+2 \sqrt{a} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-2}{a}}\right)+\csc ^{-1}(1-a)\right)\right) & 4<a<5 \\
 \frac{1}{108} \left(3 \left(8 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{a-5}}\right)-16 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a-5}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a-2}\right)+7 \pi \right)+4 \sqrt{a} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-2}{a}}\right)-6 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-5) a}}\right)+\csc ^{-1}(1-a)\right)\right) & 5<a<6 \\
 \frac{1}{108} \left(-4 \sqrt{a} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{a},\sqrt{a-5}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{a-5}{a}}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-5) a}}\right)\right)+12 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{a-5}}\right)-24 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a-5}\right)+15 \pi \right) & 6<a<8 \\
 \frac{1}{108} \left(48 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{a-8}}\right)+12 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{a-5}}\right)-24 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a-5}\right)-4 \sqrt{a} \left(-6 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-8}{a}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{a-5}{a}}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-5) a}}\right)+\cot ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{a}{a-5}}\right)\right)-9 \pi \right) & 8<a<9 \\
 \frac{1}{54} \left(12 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{a-8}}\right)+2 \sqrt{a} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-8}{a}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{(a-8) a}}\right)\right)-3 \pi \right) & 9<a<12 \\
\end{cases}
$$

And we can see this works with

```
data=Norm[#]^2 & /@ RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[ConstantArray[{-1,2},3]],10^7];
Show[Histogram[data,50,"PDF",PlotRange->All],Plot[pdf[x],{x,0,12},PlotStyle->Black],ImageSize->Large];
```

[image]

### Footnote

1. here $b-g\in\{0,1,4\}$ come from breaking the integrals up from $-1$ to $0$ and $0$ to $2$ so the new variables are $1$-to-$1$ with the old ones on those intervals.

Comment: +1. Thank you for your work. I need some time to think about it.

Comment: Something to adjust: your [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epxzH.png) is a histogram, not a formula.
Next, if you mean $\delta(k)$ as the $\delta$-distribution, then the integral $$\int _{a-b}^{a-c}\int _{w-d}^{w-e}\int _{v-f}^{v-g}\frac{\delta (k) dkdvdw}{8 \sqrt{v-k} \sqrt{w-v} \sqrt{a-w}} $$ makes no sense
in traditional math.

Comment: I accept your workaround, though the important statements
"The pieces will clearly have bounds that are integers"
and "The general idea is the pieces will be at the values of $\sum_{i=1}^d a_i^2$ with $\sum_{i=1}^d a_i^2$ in dimension $d$"
are not grounded.

Comment: @user64494 what do you mean "your formula is a histogram"? My formula is the PDF, as requested. Why wouldn't that integral make sense? It seems perfectly fine to me, Mathematica can calculate it, and it's literally a recasting of the formula from Wikipedia. When you say my statements about the pieces are not grounded, you mean they're wrong or just not explained?

Comment: I mean a bad link.

Comment: @user64494 ah I see, it should be fixed now. How about your other concerns and my responses?

Comment: I don't change my mind. The PDF  is defined only for an absolutely continuous random variable. That was discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231460/how-to-plot-this-pdf/231464#231464).

Answer (score 7):

@bRost03 has the best answer.  This following produces the desired function but not so neat and tidy.  (Some parts of the result contains imaginary numbers although when evaluated result in a non-negative real number for the density.  Maybe some simplification is possible.)

Because the density function is available for the 2D case, get the pdf's for the 1D and 2D case.  In other words we're going to look for the pdf for

$$X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2 = (X_1^2+X_2^2)+X_3^2=Z_{12}+Z_3=Z$$

```
pdf12 = PDF[TransformedDistribution[x1^2 + x2^2, {x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}],
  x2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]}], z12]
pdf3 = PDF[TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]], z3]
```

To find the pdf for $Z$ multiply the two pdf's together and replace `z3` with `z-z12`.  This gives us the joint pdf for $Z$ and $Z_{12}$.

```
jointpdf = pdf12 pdf3 /. z3 -> z - z12 // PiecewiseExpand;
```

**Note to (final?) update:**  I've removed the Do-loops and used the more standard *Mathematica* probability functions in what follows.

To find the pdf for $Z$ we obtain the marginal distribution of that bivariate pdf.

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[jointpdf, {z, 0, 12}, {z12, 0, 8}]
pdf = PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1], z]
```

This result contains some imaginary numbers that cancel out when evaluated but those can be appropriately eliminated with the following:

```
pdf[[1, All, 1]] = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[#[[1]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], 
  Assumptions -> #[[2]]] & /@ pdf[[1, All]];
```

Finally, we simplify the pdf:

```
pdf = pdf//Simplify
```

The result is

```
pdf = Piecewise[{{(-(1/27))*Pi*(-3 + Sqrt[z]), Inequality[1, Less, z, LessEqual, 2]}, {(2*Pi*Sqrt[z])/27, Inequality[0, Less, z, LessEqual, 1]}, {(1/54)*(-3*Pi + 12*ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-8 + z]] + 2*Sqrt[z]*(-ArcTan[Sqrt[z/(-8 + z)]] + ArcTan[(1/4)*Sqrt[(-8 + z)*z]])), Inequality[9, LessEqual, z, Less, 12]}, {(1/108)*(-5*Pi*(-3 + Sqrt[z]) + 12*ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-5 + z]] - 24*ArcTan[Sqrt[-5 + z]] + 2*Sqrt[z]*(2*ArcTan[2*Sqrt[(-5 + z)/z]] - 2*ArcTan[2*Sqrt[z/(-5 + z)]] - ArcTan[2/Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] + 2*ArcTan[(1/2)*Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] + ArcTan[(Sqrt[-5 + z]*z + 2*Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z])/(4 + 2*Sqrt[z])])), 6 < z < 8}, {(1/108)*(-9*Pi - 2*Pi*Sqrt[z] + 48*ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-8 + z]] + 12*ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-5 + z]] - 24*ArcTan[Sqrt[-5 + z]] + 2*Sqrt[z]*(ArcCot[2*Sqrt[z/(-5 + z)]] + 2*ArcTan[2*Sqrt[(-5 + z)/z]] - 4*ArcTan[Sqrt[z/(-8 + z)]] + 4*ArcTan[(1/4)*Sqrt[(-8 + z)*z]] - ArcTan[2/Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] - ArcTan[(2*z)/Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] + 2*ArcTan[(1/2)*Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] + ArcTan[(Sqrt[-5 + z]*z + 2*Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z])/(4 + 2*Sqrt[z])])), 8 < z < 9}, {(1/108)*(9*Pi - 4*ArcCot[2/Sqrt[3]] + 8*ArcTan[2/Sqrt[3]] - 2*Sqrt[2]*(3*Pi + ArcTan[(47940*Sqrt[6])/7199])), z == 8}, {(1/27)*(3*(Pi - 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[-2 + z]]) + Sqrt[z]*(ArcCsc[1 - z] + ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)/z]] - ArcTan[Sqrt[z/(-2 + z)]] + ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z]])), Inequality[2, Less, z, LessEqual, 3]}, {(1/54)*(5*Pi - ArcCot[2] + Sqrt[6]*ArcCot[2*Sqrt[6]] + 5*ArcTan[2] - Sqrt[6]*(5*ArcTan[Sqrt[2/3]] + 3*ArcTan[Sqrt[3/2]] + ArcTan[2*Sqrt[6]])), z == 6}, {(1/108)*(6*Pi + ArcTan[(45299420*Sqrt[2])/382087111]), z == 4}, {(1/108)*(9*Pi - 12*ArcTan[Sqrt[-2 + z]] + Sqrt[z]*(-2*ArcSec[1 - z] + 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)/z]] - ArcTan[Sqrt[z/(-2 + z)]] + 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z]] + ArcTan[2 - z - Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z], z + Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z]])), 3 < z < 4}, {(1/108)*(21*Pi - 8*Pi*Sqrt[z] + 24*ArcTan[2/Sqrt[-5 + z]] - 48*ArcTan[Sqrt[-5 + z]] - 12*ArcTan[Sqrt[-2 + z]] + 2*Sqrt[z]*(2*ArcCot[2*Sqrt[z/(-5 + z)]] + ArcCsc[1 - z] + 4*ArcTan[2*Sqrt[(-5 + z)/z]] + ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)/z]] - 2*ArcTan[2/Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] - 2*ArcTan[(2*z)/Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] + 4*ArcTan[(1/2)*Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z]] - ArcTan[Sqrt[z/(-2 + z)]] + ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z]] + 2*ArcTan[(Sqrt[-5 + z]*z + 2*Sqrt[(-5 + z)*z])/(4 + 2*Sqrt[z])])), 5 < z < 6}, {(1/108)*(Pi*(33 - 13*Sqrt[z]) - 12*ArcTan[Sqrt[-2 + z]] + Sqrt[z]*(2*ArcCsc[1 - z] + 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)/z]] - ArcTan[Sqrt[z/(-2 + z)]] + 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z]] + ArcTan[2 - z - Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z], z + Sqrt[(-2 + z)*z]])), 4 < z < 5}, {(1/216)*(58*Pi - 23*Sqrt[5]*Pi + 2*Sqrt[5]*ArcSin[7/128]), z == 5}}, 0]
```

**Update:**  Below is all of the code in one place with approximate execution times:

```
(* About 12 seconds *)
pdf12 = PDF[TransformedDistribution[x1^2 + x2^2,
   {x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}],
    x2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]}], z12]
pdf3 = PDF[TransformedDistribution[x^2,
  x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]], z3]
jointpdf = pdf12 pdf3 /. z3 -> z - z12 // PiecewiseExpand;
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[jointpdf, {z, 0, 12}, {z12, 0, 8}];

(* About 10 minutes *)
pdf = PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1], z];

(* About 2 minutes *)
pdf[[1, All, 1]] = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[#[[1]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}],
     Assumptions -> #[[2]]] & /@ pdf[[1, All]];

(* About 1 second *)
pdf = pdf // Simplify
```

Comment: Thank you. Some places which I don't understand: "Now find the joint pdf for $Z$ and $Z−X_{12}$" and "Integrate out $Z_{12}$ "($Z_{12}$ is a random variable.). Could you explain those? There are other unclear pieces too. TIA.

Comment: $X_{12}$ should have been $Z_{12}$.  And I've modified the notion a bit so hopefully things are more standard.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand " integrate out `z12`:".

Comment: The quick answer is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions.  I'll add more details tomorrow.

Comment: +1.Thank you. I got it. Poor comments make it difficult to understand a good job.

Comment: The command `PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  a + b, {a \[Distributed] 
    TransformedDistribution[
     x1^2 + x2^2, {x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}], 
      x2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]}], 
   b \[Distributed] 
    TransformedDistribution[x3^2, 
     x3 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 2}]]}], t]` produces a similar output in several hours. The result is not correct since `NIntegrate[%, {t, -1, 13}]` performs `0.513086`.

Comment: Could you elaborate your `Assumptions -> #[[2]]] & /@ f[[i]]` and `r = {#[[1]], {z12, #[[2, 1]], #[[2, 5]]}} & /@ r;`? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Done.  And using `Rubi` (https://rulebasedintegration.org/) speeds most integrals considerably but unfortunately there are some that `Rubi` doesn't handle.

Comment: No, the assumptions still are not explained. You perform `pdf` on one of the pieces. I don't understand the pieces (e.g `3<z<5`) too. BTW, your code is very slowly executed. I see only digits 1...6 on my comp at the moment.

Comment: One multiplies the two piecewise pdf's (for $Z_{12}$ and $Z_3=Z-Z_{12})$ and the result is a piecewise function with 10 functions to integrate.  For the 5-th piece of that piecewise function the resulting restriction is `1 < z-z12 < 4 && 5 < z12 < 8'.  I then `Reduce` that to two disjoint sets:  `{{6 < z ≤ 9, 5 < z12 < -1+z}, {9 < z < 12,-4+z < z12 < 8}}`.  For the first piece one integrates `z12` over `5` to `z-1` with the assumption that `z` is between `6` and `9`.  Is it an explanation of the code or the probability theory that you want?

Comment: Thank you. I got the pieces. BTW, I still see only `1...6` on my comp.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `1...6`.  Are the integrals for 7 through 10 not completing?  I'm using Windows 10, Mathematica 12.3.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in 12.3 on Windows 10 Pro. I obtained several intervals of kind `(-(1/2) - I/2) ((-1 + I) + z + Sqrt[(-2 + z) z]) \[Element] Reals && 
 3 < z <= 5` and the imaganary unit in some pieces, e.g. `1/216 (-2 \[Pi] + 8 \[Pi] Sqrt[-1 + z] + 
   Sqrt[z] (4 \[Pi] + 4 ArcSec[1 - z] + 
      I Log[(-1 + z) (-1 + z + Sqrt[(-2 + z) z])] + 
      2 I Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) ((-1 + I) + z + Sqrt[(-2 + z) z])]))`.  See the executed code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izao0ou6mxnbxyl/temp.pdf?dl=0) at the bottom.

Comment: I see that.  I just copied my code above and it ran fine (around 15 minutes).  So I wonder where those `(-(1/2) - I/2) ((-1 + I) + z + Sqrt[(-2 + z) z]) \[Element] Reals` are coming from.  If you print `jointpdf`, are they in there?  (More proof that @bRost03 's answer is better.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce your final update:  the command `pdfz = PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1], z]` is running without any response on my comp more than 10 hoers.

Comment: I see from your comment I have one more typo: it should be `pdf` rather than `pdfz` in the code you listed.  However, that would not stop that piece of code from completing.  I've copied-and-pasted from all of the code above and it finishes on my PC in about 11 minutes.

Comment: Sorry,I am tired. All the best.

Comment: I'm sorry, too, that it isn't working for you.  I have yet to install 12.3 on my other computer.  After doing so, I'll see if it works or not there.