# Unclear piece of the documentation to BinomialDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Looking in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinomialDistribution.html?v=13.1#11493) , I read

> The probability density and cumulative distribution functions may be given using `PDF[BinomialDistribution[n,p],x]` and `CDF[BinomialDistribution[n,p],x]`.
> The mean, median, variance, raw moments, and central moments may be computed using `Mean`, `Median`, `Variance`,
> `Moment`, and `CentralMoment`, respectively. These quantities can be visualized using `DiscretePlot`

and see an example

```
pdf=PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], k]
```

> `Piecewise[{{(1 - p)^(-k + n)*p^k*Binomial[n, k], 0 <= k <= n}}, 0]`

But this does not possess usual properties of  a PDF. For example,

```
n = 5; p = 1/3; NIntegrate[pdf, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `0.950953`

and such a definition causes many bugs. Here is one of these.

```
 ClearAll[n, p, x, y, n]; pdf =  PDF[TransformedDistribution[ Max[x, y/n], 
{Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], Distributed[y, BinomialDistribution[n, p]]}], t];
 FullSimplify[pdf, Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers && 0 < p && p < 1 && t \[Element] Reals]
```

> `Piecewise[{{1 - (1 - p)^(-1 + n - Floor[n*t])*p^(1 + Floor[n*t])*Binomial[n, 1 + Floor[n*t]]* Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n + Floor[n*t], 2 + Floor[n*t], p/(-1 + p)],  Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 1] && n*t > Floor[n*t]}, {0, (t < 0 || t > 1) && n*t > Floor[n*t]}},Indeterminate]`

```
n = 5; p = 1/3; NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{1 - (1 - p)^(-1 + n - Floor[n*t])*p^(1 + Floor[n*t])*
Binomial[n, 1 + Floor[n*t]]*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n + Floor[n*t], 2 + Floor[n*t], 
p/(-1 + p)], Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 1] && n*t > Floor[n*t]}, {0, (t < 0 || t > 1) && 
n*t > Floor[n*t]}},Indeterminate], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `0.666662`

The same issues with other discrete distributions and dozens of bugs may be presented in this field.

The question arises: is the quoted documentation correct or I don't understand something?

Answer (score 4):

For discrete distributions use Sum:

```
Sum[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], k], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

(* Piecewise[{{1, n >= 0}}, 0] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest to the question. I am  out of MMA at the moment so I'll give my response later
.

Comment: It's honestly a bit unfortunate that in WL the function `PDF` is used for proper PDFs but also for PMFs. Those are definitely not the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, `n = 5; p = 1/3; NSum[
 Piecewise[{{1 - (1 - p)^(-1 + n - Floor[n*t])*p^(1 + Floor[n*t])*
      Binomial[n, 1 + Floor[n*t]]*
      Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n + Floor[n*t], 2 + Floor[n*t], 
       p/(-1 + p)], 
    Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 1] && 
     n*t > Floor[n*t]}, {0, (t < 0 || t > 1) && n*t > Floor[n*t]}}, 
  Indeterminate], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` fails as well as `Sum`.  Also such an approach is not documented. Conclusion -- this is not it. Thank you anyway. I wonder the upvoters.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: Are you serious?

Comment: The distribution `Max[x, y/n]` is a mixture of a continuous and discrete distributions. WL doesn't handle these particularly well, unfortunately. Probably related to the way PDF muddles discrete and continuous two together. `CDF` handles these cases a little better, IIRC.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: Sorry, the command `n=5;p=1/3;pdf =  PDF[TransformedDistribution[ Max[x, y/n], 
{Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], Distributed[y, BinomialDistribution[n, p]]}], t];
 FullSimplify[pdf, Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers && 0 < p && p < 1 && t \[Element] Reals]` produces a wrong result without any warning/error. The documentation to `TransformedDistribution` does not include any restrictions on  a mixture of a continuous and discrete distributions. Therefore, this is a bug.

Comment: No need to get defensive. Of course it's a bug. I'm just saying to use CDF for situations like these since it's more likely to give the right result.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit:  Indeed, the result of `FullSimplify[
 CDF[TransformedDistribution[
   Max[x, y/n], {Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], 
    Distributed[y, BinomialDistribution[n, p]]}], t], 
 Assumptions -> 
  n \[Element] PositiveIntegers && p > 0 && p < 1 && 
   t \[Element] Reals]` seem to be correct. The attempt to express `PDF` through `DiracDelta` is difficult to realize.

Comment: @user64494 You've commented (maybe more than once) that "The PDF exists only for absolutely continuous distributions...." (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231460/how-to-plot-this-pdf) which this distribution is not absolutely continuous.  Have you had a change of heart?  Or is the issue that *Mathematica* gives a result for something that doesn't exist?

Comment: @JimB: The latest one. I'd like to repeat "The attempt to express `PDF` through `DiracDelta` is difficult to realize". BTW, Maple fails with it.

Comment: Is that 3 part conditional result really correct? Is it described in some book?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you. Pronouns are misleading. Deep regard.